# What is a better way to load and unload on UIImageVIews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

Good day all. I need help in understanding if I am doing the right thing or not on the subject of `UIImageViews`.

Scenario:

1. I have a `mainViewController` and 3 `UIViewController`s.
2. Each of the 3 `viewControllers` has at least 20 `UIImageViews`. The PNG files are around 20-30kb each and most of them has transparent parts and are not in an array.
3. When 1 of the 3 `viewcontroller` loads, I `alloc` and `init` all the `UIImageviews` With Images.
4. Using buttons, I call an array of BOOLs to turn the images ON or OFF as I go from pages to pages - around 7-10.
5. It works but I find that it is working a bit slow especially when I loaded it on the iphone.

Queries:

1. Any better way of doing it based from your experiences?
2. Will it be better if I just use 7-10 view controllers then load what is really needed in the scene? (I really needed just half of it per scene on the average but my understanding is that using viewControllers will be "heavier")
3. Any reading material or link that may lead me to answering this issue?
4. When I go back to `mainViewController` using modal `segue`, do all `UIImageViews` on the current `Viewcontroller` then unload automatically? (ARC ON)

Thanks.

Comment: #4 no, and you should never go back to a previous controller with a segue, unless it's an unwind segue. If you go back with an unwind, or in code with dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, then the controller you're leaving will be deallocated.

Comment: @rdelmar. With what you said, if I create separate `UIViewCOntroller`s then load `UIImageviews` separately then use `seque` to switch pages, all UIImageView along with its images will be there until I Use `unwindsegue`? which will then consume CPU space more than what I currently have?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know how you're switching between your controllers now. When you go back to a previous controller, do you want to go back to the same instance, or will a new instance work?

Comment: @rdelmar, currently they are the same instances created in the XIB (mainViewController,3 containers and segues) all subviews are coded. I have never tried creating instance of`UIVIewController` by just code. What is the difference between new and same?

Comment: If you need the controller to look like it was when you left it, when you come back, then you need to use the same instance. If you don't, then that controller can be deallocated when you leave it which will free up memory (although with images, you have to make sure they're not getting cached). Which way to go depends on your needs, and whether you really need to conserve memory.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for that. I will do more research on this issue, at least I have something to start with.